# Loop through an array and get the values to pass it on dom element

Tags: javascript

How can I get selected option values in the array and pass it to DOM elements? and then call the element value in REST API to add items.Thanks for the help.

Here is my code.

```
var myArray = ["#txtDepartment ","#txtLocation" ];
$.each(myArray, function(index, choices) {
    $(choices).change(function () {
       var selectedText =$(choices).find("option:selected").text();     
    });
});
```

REST API

```
function addListItem() {    
    var title = $("#txtTitle").val();
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ComputerEquipment')/items";

    $.ajax({
       url: fullUrl,
       type: "POST",
       data: JSON.stringify({
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ComputerEquipmentListItem' },   
           'Title': title,
           'Department': ,
           'Location':,
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/test/WebParts/Fruits/test2.js"></script>

<strong>Department:</strong>
<select id="txtDepartment">
    <option value="HR">HR</option>
    <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
    <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>    
</select>
<br/>
<strong>Location:</strong>
<select id="txtLocation">
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="USA">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="UK">Malaysia</option>    
    <option value="Canada">Philippines</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is wrong with `'Department': $("#txtDepartment").val()`? And what are your plans with `selectedText `

Comment: @mplungjan there might be some `value` attribute added in the option and in that condition, `.val()` gives the value from attribute, not from the text in the `option` tag.

Comment: @JessieBear, question still not clear. What do you want to do? You have the values from selected dropdowns. Now when this `addListItem()` function should be executed. Did you bind some event on the selector?

Comment: @AshishKumar - then `'Department': $("#txtDepartment option:selected").text();`

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan! I just use this one it's more simple.'Department': $("#txtDepartment option:selected").text(); I didn't use the array.

Comment: So if that solved the issue, please delete the question